# What's the most performant way to reverse a lookup on a dict of tuples?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a choices field, with a list of tuples:

```
EVENT_CHOICES = [(1, "queued"), (2, "sent"), (3, "failed")]
```

This is stored as a `PositiveSmallIntegerField` rather than a `CharField` for performant reasons:

```
event_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=EVENT_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

In my app, the field is populated by a webhook to an external source, which `POSTS` the `str` component of the tuple. E.g. I receive `queued`, `sent`, or `failed` as a `POST` variable.

What's the easiest/most performant way to reverse a lookup on `EVENT_CHOICES` to return the `int` from the `str`?

E.g, a clumsy long form way would be:

```
if event == "queued":
   event_type = 1
if event == "sent":
   event_type = 2
if event == "failed":
   event_type = 3
```

Given I actually have a lot of choices, I assume there has to be a neater way for this?

Comment: If you're only receiving the `str` in each call, and there is no way to access the `list`, i would assume storing a `dict` with the `str` as keys and numbers as values may be your best option. Then you could just call `d.get('queued')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you just need to do one lookup you can just iterate it

```
def get_idx(choice):
    for idx,evt in EVENT_CHOICES:
        if evt == choice:
           return idx
```

or if you are going to do it more than once you should  create a reverse dict

```
dataReversed = {choice:idx for idx,choice in EVENT_CHOICES}
dataReversed.get('queued')
```